# Getting Result as Undefined while finding out Prime Factors

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, prime-factoring

So i am working on a simple code to find all prime factors of a number, i can do it using for loop but i tried this approach ,so if someone can help me with the output as it's coming undefined. I tried using for loop and it's working but when using this method i get undefined.

```
let arr1=[]; 
let recursion={
    primeFactorize:(num,n=2)=>
    {
        if(num%n==0 && n<=num)
        {
            arr1.push(n);
            num/=n;
            recursion.primeFactorize(num,n+=1);
        }
        else if(n>num){
            return arr1;
        }
        else{
            recursion.primeFactorize(num,n+=1);
        }
    }
};
console.log(recursion.primeFactorize(35));
```

Expected result is Array but i get an undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The function doesn't return anything, it just builds the array. Try logging the array instead.

```js
let arr1=[]; 
let recursion={
    primeFactorize:(num,n=2)=>
    {
        if(num%n==0 && n<=num)
        {
            arr1.push(n);
            num/=n;
            recursion.primeFactorize(num,n+=1);
        }
        else if(n>num){
            return arr1;
        }
        else{
            recursion.primeFactorize(num,n+=1);
        }
    }
};

recursion.primeFactorize(35)
console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: But how about else if , ofcourse n will become greater than num so it qualifies for else if statement which returns the array.

Comment: and also after logging the array it still provides undefined

Comment: @JohnnyDepp - no it doesn't. hit the blue "run code snippet" button. if you would like another example, i wrote [this function](https://github.com/Pamblam/Methodus/blob/master/src/generatePrimes.js) for project euler. feel free to use it.

Comment: thnx bud !! I got it and ur repo is great help !! Bro Fist.

Comment: happy to help. i posted the wrong function tho, meant to direct you [here](https://github.com/Pamblam/Methodus/blob/master/src/primeFactors.js).

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything in the recursive cases. Put `return` before `recursion.primeFactorize` in both places it appears inside of itself.